# Associate post comment with a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, associations

I have an application that allows users to comment on a post.

`rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text post:references`

How can I change it so the `commenter` is set as the user who posted the comment

Comment: Could you precise it slightly? Do you want your Comment model to return User who wrote the comment? If so, do you want this column to be string or are you ok with user id?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough. Yes, I want the comment model to return the specific user who made the comment. I don't want it to be a string (ie... at the moment the user can enter a "commenter" name) I only want the user to be able to enter text into the body, and their user_id is associated with that comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make association:

```
rails generate model Comment author_id:integer body:text post:references

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :author, class_name: <User or whatever your user model is called>, foreign_key: :author_id

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, foreign_key: :author_id
end
```

You will also need to assign this value when new comment is created:

```
#Comment controller? Hard to say how it is being saved from the code you posted. :P

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      ...
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to solve the problem.

`rails generate model Comment user_id:integer body:text listing:references`

add `:user_id` to `attr_accessible` in the `\app\models\comments.rb` file then add the hidden attribute to the comment form:

`<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>`

Then use `<%= comment.user.id %>` and/or `<%= comment.user.name %>`